# How to insert user login datetime in mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in PHP and I would like to store the users login time in another table called LoginHistory, I don't know how to write a query. Can u help me on that please?

```
<?php
include_once "conn.php";

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["mobile_no"]) && empty($_POST["log_password"])) {
echo '<script>alert("Both Fields are required") </script>';
}
$sql = "select * from Users where Mobile='" . $_POST['mobile_no'] . "' and 
Password='" . md5($_POST['log_password']) . "'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
if ($rowcount > 0) {
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION["userId"] = $row['Id'];
$_SESSION["ConstituencyId"] = $row['ConstituencyId'];
$succmsg = "Login Success";
header("location:user-login-welcome.php");
} else {
$errmsg = "Invalid Username / Password..";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more information, do you have a table for this purpose and what are the names of these fields. I gave an answer already, but I might be able to improve this if I have a bit more context of the application and database structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your login success condition just add your insert code to insert date in another table

```
if ($rowcount > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION["userId"] = $row['Id'];
    $_SESSION["ConstituencyId"] = $row['ConstituencyId'];
    $succmsg = "Login Success";
   // Add your login time insert code like below
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES ('$date')");
    header("location:user-login-welcome.php");
}
```

You can change `datetime`, Check the date time manual of
[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how known you are with database connections but assuming you know how to create a PDO connection (if not checkout this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and you have an available database with a LoginHistory table containing a username (VARCHAR) and timestamp (DATETIME) column, it isn't that hard to write.

Lets assume your connection in stored in the $pdo variable. The only thing you need to do is write an insert statement that inserts the username and the current timestamp into the database. An insert statement can be written like this:

```
INSERT INTO LoginHistory (username, timestamp) VALUES (:username, :timestamp)
```

If you want to execute this statement using PDO the code could look like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO LoginHistory (username, timestamp) VALUES (:username, :timestamp)');
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':timestamp', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$stmt->execute();
```

If you don't have a table in your database for this purpose yet, I would advise taking a look at this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE LoginHistory
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    timestamp datetime NOT NULL
);
```

You also might want to look at your current statement for fetching users. By using concatination to insert variables into you queries, users can alter your query by setting a post value, if I submit the login form using this value for mobile_no (expection mobile_no is the username), I should get logged in:

```
a_username_that_does_not_exist' OR Mobile='mobile of admin'; --
```

If you want to prevent this, you can use prepared statements, see the insert example and the PDO docs for more information.

A safe way of writing your statements should be like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=db_name;charset=UTF8;','root','password');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Mobile=:mobile AND Password=:password');
$stmt->bindValue(':mobile', $_POST['mobile_no']);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', md5($_POST['log_password']));
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($user) {
    // User is logged in
}
```

I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try to get date and insert it to your table

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`date`) VALUES ('$date')");
```